# Window is undefined in Nextjs but values are needed in useState

Tags: reactjs, next.js

Trying to get the exact window values as the screen size changes. How can i get the window values into useState()? Since useState cannot be used in a conditional, and window is undefined outside a useEffect?

```
    const isSSR = typeof window !== "undefined";
    const [windowSize, setWindowSize] = React.useState({
        width: isSSR ? 1200 : window.innerWidth,
        height: isSSR ? 800 : window.innerHeight,
    });

    function changeWindowSize() {
        setWindowSize({ width: window.innerWidth, height: window.innerHeight });
    }

    React.useEffect(() => {
        window.addEventListener("resize", changeWindowSize);

        return () => {
            window.removeEventListener("resize", changeWindowSize);
        };
    }, []);

    return windowSize;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things to be corrected,

1. Your `isSSR` logic is not right. due to that, `window.innerWidth` and `window.innerHeight` were evaluated in the server. It should be `===` not `!==`.

```
const isSSR = typeof window === "undefined";
```

2. And change the client-side function to be safe like below.

```
function changeWindowSize() {
    if(!isSSR){
        setWindowSize({ width: window.innerWidth, height: window.innerHeight });
    }
}
```

*** `changeWindowSize` change is not needed since you call it only within a `useEffect` and `useEffect` hook is not executed in the server.

Comment: @NJAS, check this out !!

Comment: You don't need to change `changeWindowSize` though, it's implemented in `useEffect` so that should be fine